# How to get full text in Twitter search API?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have used twitter search API and also incorporated the `extended_mode` and `full_text` attributes but I am still getting a truncated string from the API

Here is my code:

```
results = t.search(q='tuberculosis', count=50, lang='en', result_type='popular',tweet_mode='extended')
all_tweets = results['statuses']

for tweet in all_tweets:
        tweetString = tweet["full_text"]
        userMentionList = tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
        if len(userMentionList)>0:
            for eachUserMention in userMentionList:
                name = eachUserMention["screen_name"]
                time = tweet["created_at"]
                wks.insert_rows(wks.rows, values=[tweetString, name, time], inherit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using TwitterSearch, following should work:

```
tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
tso.set_keywords('tuberculosis')
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    print(tweet['text'])
```

you can set your desired attributes like language and count of course

Comment: I haven't tried yours but the tweet is truncated only for retweets